# Redirect user to custom URL after successful registration in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla1.7

I want my users to redirect to a custom URL after they successfully register in Joomla .
I can't find any option for that !
How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Joomla!'s built-in menu to load the registration page, or getting there from the Login module there isn't a way to redirect (which is odd because you can set a redirect after login in the login module).

The best place to start would be to look at existing solutions in the "[Authentication](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication)" section of the [Joomla! Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/). It appears there are several listed that support both the old 1.5 style sites and the new 1.7/2.5 sites.

*(By the way if you are still on 1.7 you should update to the latest 2.5 as there are serious security issues in the 1.7 line.)*

Answer (score 0):

In your code set do the following;

```
$app=JFactory::getapplication();
$app->redirect('index.php?option=com_users&view=login'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a plugin (at least in Joomla 3.x - not sure how far back this will work off-hand). Key here is the onUserAfterSave event, which tells you whether the user is new or existing.

I wrote the code below some time ago, so can't recall the exact reason the redirect could not be done from within the onUserAfterSave event handler, but I think the redirect is subsequently overridden elsewhere in the core Joomla user management code if you try to do it from there, hence saving a flag in the session and checking it in a later event handler.

```
class PlgUserSignupRedirect extends JPlugin
{
    public function onUserAfterSave($user, $isnew, $success, $msg)
    {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();

        // If the user isn't new we don't act
        if (!$isnew) {
            return false;
        }

        $session = JFactory::getSession();
        $session->set('signupRedirect', 1);

        return true;
    }

    function onAfterRender() {
        $session = JFactory::getSession();
        if ($session->get('signupRedirect')) {
            JFactory::getApplication()->redirect('/my-post-signup-url');
            $session->clear('signupRedirect');
        }
    }
}
```